# override URL with backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, fetch

This is my Backbone Collection:

var ForcastCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend({

```
url: 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/',

apiKey: '123456789',

coords: '37.8267,-122.423',
```

})

And this is my Backbone Router:

var ForcastRouter=Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{

```
    '*anyroute':'showDefault'   

},

showDefault: ()=>{
    var fc=new ForcastCollection();

    window.fc=fc;
    fc.fetch({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:{

            'api-key':fc.apiKey,
            coords:fc.coords

        },
```

When I dont send data in the fetch and make the URL in the collection look like this:
url: api.forecast.io/forecast/123456789/37.8267,-122.423
I get the response from the server and its OK.

But! when I pass it the data object, it messes up the URL and I get a 404 response.

My question is how can override the URL so the fetch wont mess it up?

The fecth makes my URL look like this:

https://api.forecast.io/forecast/forecast/123456789/?callback=jQuery214039465020946227014_1443044539066&=37.8267%2C-122.423&_=1443044539067

instesd of this:

https://api.forecast.io/forecast/123456789/37.8267,-122.423

please help...

Answer (score 0):

found the solution here:
https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/15/searching-with-a-backbonejs-collection/

the solution is in the article